# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused & Could not connect to the endpoint URL: http://127.0.0.1:3001

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, botocore

I am trying to run integration tests using boto3 and aws. It seems the tests are unable to connect to the localhost endpoint so the tests are failing. I'm quite sure I've configured my aws environment variables correctly. I suspect that maybe there is no local server running but I'm still unsure how to fix the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running on Mac Mojave, I've tried changing the ports that the server is attempting to connect to localhost:3000. I've also tried connecting to a server that I'm running using AWS Step Functions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-config-options.html) but with no luck.

Error messages from Log:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

and

```
raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/2015-03-31/functions/AthenaDatabaseProvider/invocations"
```

Complete Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 262, in send
    chunked=self._chunked(request.headers),
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 344, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 125, in _send_request
    method, url, body, headers, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 152, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 236, in send
    return super(AWSConnection, self).send(str)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 183, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPConnection object at 0x11ea50d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/patrickward/repositories/JAM/hobbes/transformations/tests/integration/lambdas/athena_database_provider_test.py", line 97, in test_drop_with_stack_false_keeps_database_on_delete
    invoke_fn(cloud_formation_event('Delete', DatabaseName=existent_database, DropWithStack='False'))
  File "/Users/patrickward/repositories/JAM/hobbes/transformations/tests/integration/lambdas/athena_database_provider_test.py", line 54, in _exec
    Payload=json.dumps(event)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 231, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 244, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/Users/patrickward/.local/share/virtualenvs/hobbes-iOpBOaJm/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 282, in send
    raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/2015-03-31/functions/AthenaDatabaseProvider/invocations"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I need to have the docker app running when I run tests. Hope this can help someone who might have run into the same problem!

Comment: This was equally my issue